# Python default behavior eats all input lines, leaving EOFError for next script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ubuntu, cygwin, stdin

It appears Python is a greedy taker of input lines?

Very simple Python3 script: testinput.py

```
for i in range(5):
    x = input()
    print(f'{i}. {x}')
```

Python script is called repeatedly by Bash script: testinput.sh

```
python3 testinput.py
python3 testinput.py
python3 testinput.py
```

Input file: testinput.txt

```
wo
wajf
wajf
jwfao
ksd
3
34
35
w45
54w
seg
jawfo
34j
serg
se
se
gser
gg
erg
segrse
rg
g
esg
g
g
erg
serg
serg
seg
:wq
```

Now I feed testinput.txt to testinput.sh:

```
bash testinput.sh < testinput.txt
```

And I get:

```
0. wo
1. wajf
2. wajf
3. jwfao
4. ksd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testinput.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testinput.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How do I make each invocation of python3 take only the input lines it needs? thanks!
(Tested in Ubuntu and Cygwin, so unlikely to be platform dependent)

Comment: just one info, if you try to input the values by hand calling just `bash testinput.sh` it works without error, same if your bash script just use one call instead of three `cat testinput.sh` : `python3 testinput.py`, looks like the code is being broken in the second call of `python3 testinput.py`

Comment: This is expected behaviour for python scripts. Using *nix program such as `(head -n2; head -n2; head -n2) < testinput.txt` will work as you expect. Python may do something different for console input vs file input on a windows console, but in general python intends to provide the same behaviour on all platforms.